# Point for a badge is mysteriously gone

Tags: bug, reputation, badges

I was checking a badge in my profile and I found something a little bit weird.

Today was a good day, 246 points, so I should have earned another point in my race to the "epic" badge... but when I click the badge, I see in the description that I have for today 180 of 200 in the reputation of today...

Where did the other 60 reputation go? Why are they not there?

[image]